# Is this a topological ring?

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be any ring and put the topology on it, which is generated by requiring that one-point sets be closed. Is $R$ a topological ring? I.e. are addtion $R\times R\to R$ and multiplication $R\times R\to R$ continous with respect to the product topology?

Comment: what are your thoughts on it?

Comment: My thoughts are, that the preimage of a one-point set $\{z\}$ under addition is $\{(x,y)\mid x+y=z\}$ and I don't see how to prove or disprove this is closed in general; similarly for multiplication.

Comment: include that in the question please. But if you want to check it's continuity, check the open sets, what are the open sets of $R$?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the topology is the smallest so that each point is closed, you are considering the cofinite topology on $R$. So a neighborhood of $0$ is of the form $R\setminus F$, where $F\subseteq R$ is finite and $0\notin F$.

A necessary condition for the ring with such topology to be a topological ring is that, for every neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ so that $V+V\subseteq U$.

For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $U=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{1\}$. Can you find a suitable $V$?